# No funciona el script "alert()"

Tags: javascript, alert

No se porque no me funciona el alert, si asi aparece en mi clase de programacion, no se mucho de estas cosas pero estoy aprendiendo y nose porque no funciona el alert si lo hice igual al del profesor :c.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mi primer HTML, te amo hermana</title>
  <style>
  body
  {
    background-color: #3f5a96;
    color: rgb(201, 91, 91);
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  strong
  {
    background-color: #3a6e36;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hola <strong>mama ya casi</strong> aprendo</p>
  <p>XD hola genteeeee UwU</p>
<script>
alert:("mami te amooooo");
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Recomiendo repases la sintaxis justo aquí: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/alert esos `:` salen sobrando

Comment: Amigo no olvides marcar una opcion como correcta, para que la pregunta no quede abierta

Answer (score 1):

Amigo solo es un error de sintaxis, quitale los : que estan entre el alert y el (). Prueba asi:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mi primer HTML, te amo hermana</title>
  <style>
  body
  {
    background-color: #3f5a96;
    color: rgb(201, 91, 91);
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  }
  strong
  {
    background-color: #3a6e36;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hola <strong>mama ya casi</strong> aprendo</p>
  <p>XD hola genteeeee UwU</p>
<script>
alert("mami te amooooo");
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consejo: cuando se trata de errores de sintaxis solo se debe esperar (o participar) votando para el cierre de la publicación

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la info, donde puedo leer mas al respecto de eso ??

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Gracias amigo !!

Comment: Estuve leyendo y tienes toda la razon Bro !!

Answer (score 0):

No funciona el *alert* porque le pusiste dos puntos

```js
alert:("hello world");
```

Por esa razón no te funciona, debe ir así:

```js
alert ("hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error *"evidente"* en la sintaxis, cambia:

```
alert:("mami te amooooo");
```

por:

```
alert("mami te amooooo");
```

Lo he entrecomillado porque el navegador no lanza ningún error en la consola, el script se ejecuta de forma silenciosa si lo incluyes en un documento HTML, y algo intrigante, si añades tu código directamente en la consola funciona como un si escribieras un string directamente:

```
"mami te amooooo";
```

o como sería el caso, un string entre paréntesis.

*Me parece recordar, pero no puedo confirmarlo, porque ahora mismo no he podido encontrar nada, que las funciones `alert()` y `confirm()` dejarán de funcionar próximamente (año 2022) en Chrome y otros navegadores, por lo que habría que dejar de utilizarlos.*

Answer (score 0):

En tu `<script>alert:("Mensaje");</script>` está mal escrito, debe ser

```
<script>alert("Mensaje");</script>
```

se escribe sin los dos `:`